# How to check if a PDF had a header, before creating iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary from a page

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, itext

I am processing some pdf documents using `iTextSharp.text.pdf` and need to check if the header is null before I try to create the PdfDictionary. Below is the relevant code, I am not sure what to call to check for a null header before I call `reader.GetPageN(i)`
VB.net:

```
Public Function TestLinks(bytes As Byte(), ByRef hasLink As Boolean, ByRef hasError As String)
        Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(bytes)
        Dim pageCount As Integer = reader.NumberOfPages

        For i As Integer = 1 To pageCount
            Dim pageDictionary As PdfDictionary = reader.GetPageN(i)
```

C#

```
public object TestLinks(byte[] bytes, ref bool hasLink, ref string hasError)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
    int pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;


    for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
        PdfDictionary pageDictionary = reader.GetPageN(i);
```

Comment: In general it is unclear whether some pdf has a header or not.

Comment: @mkl well when I call `reader.GetPageN(i)` and there is no header an exception is thrown, I would rather be able to check prior to calling that method if there is a header so I am not throwing an unnecessary exception.

Comment: `reader.GetPageN(i)` has nothing to do with headers. Which headers do you actually mean? Page header lines?

Comment: @mkl when I get a chance I will update the question with the exception being thrown.